# Node + SSL = SLOW

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, socket.io

I have set up a node.js-server for running a chat service used by our site. It works. However some customers are NOT able to connect (is done automatically via javascript). They never pop up in the list of connected users (in ie 7,8,9).

My site is running on https (port 443) and therefore my node.js-server is also running on SSL (port 8443) (with the same certificate).

I am using Node 0.6.20 (have tried numerous other versions). I have the following package-setup:

```
{
    "name":"My Chat",
    "description":"Chat app using socket.io",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "dependencies":{
        "express":"3.x.x",
        "socket.io":"~0.8.7"
        },
    "engines":{"node":"0.6.20"}
}
```

and my node server looks like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var sio = require('socket.io');

var https_options = {
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('cert/certificate.pfx'),
    passphrase: "password"
};
var PORT = 8443;
var HOST = '0.0.0.0';


var myArray = new Object();
var userArray = {};
var nicknames = {};

app = express();

    app.use(app.router);

server = https.createServer(https_options, app).listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log('HTTPS Server listening on %s:%s', HOST, PORT);


var io = sio.listen(server);

io.set("transports", [ 'websocket'
   , 'flashsocket'
   , 'htmlfile'
   , 'polling'
   , 'xhr-polling'
   , 'jsonp-polling']);


// routes
app.get('/hey', function(req, res) {
    res.send('HEY!');
});
app.post('/ho', function(req, res) {
    res.send('HO!');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {


});
```

Comment: There used to be a nicely written article on Socket.io's Github wiki about ports & firewalls, but it seems it has been taken down. So I can't back it up with a source, but I seem to remember that running a server on anything but :80 and :443 was problematic. Try running the server on your primary domain on a subdomain with a standard port.

Comment: If you're still using node v0.6.x, you should really consider upgrading to the latest v0.10.

Comment: @mscdex No. Doesn't work well with the npm modules I need which you can tell from my package.json above.

Comment: @RikkusRukkus that makes no sense.